# Limiting the number of requests from a valid user in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a scenario where a user with a valid Personal Access Token makes thousands of calls to create work items in Azure DevOps. I went through all the documentation but couldn't find anything. One can enable conditional access but that would not cover this. The rate-limits etc are all default and there is no option to control those. Is there a way to control the number of requests a valid user can make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to control the number of requests a valid user can make?

I am afraid there is no such way to do this at this moment.

In my personal opinion, this request is reasonable.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]